# Can't load Rlexer as lexer or parser in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-errors, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I installed Java on my system + I also read the content on the Internet, but still, because I use IDE, I only get this error. At the same time, I want to tokenize a text file using lexer, and I get this error. How can I fix this error?
[image]

Comment: (1) Antlr is very picky on parser and lexer grammar names. Always, always, always have the grammar name ending with a capital "L" "Lexer" for a split lexer grammar, capital "P" "Parser" for a split parser grammar. Rename your grammar file names to be exactly the same name. (2) You may not need it in your driver, which may only call to get tokens, but TestRig may still want a minimal parser grammar. Use `parser grammar XParser; options { tokenVocab = XLexer; } start: .* EOF;`. (3) There's no start rule in a lexer. Use "start" from the parser grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: The problem was that when we right-clicked on the grammar file and selected the **Generate Antlr Recognizer** option, we had to mark the **gen** directory that contained the Java file as the root source.
[image]
Java file was not in our output directory (**out**), the IDE could not find Java files and because of this it gave the above mentioned error..